# Setting background image to dropbox file doesn't update background

Tags: data-synchronization, desktop, dropbox, file-transfer

Im trying to have my desktop background be an image stored on my dropbox account. My dropbox folder is linked in my home directory. When i set the background to this photo and then change the photo the background doesn't follow. I know the file has changed by opening in Finder.

If I reboot the machine the image changes so it must be cached somewhere?

Comment: This is not a question, what is your question?

Comment: @unknowndomain I believe he wants to know how to change the background using 3rd parties such as dropbox. Quite a valid question, but I bet it has little to do with dropbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it is cached. So if you want to change the desktop image, you'll need to change the db file. In Yosemite, that is `~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db`

And [here's a way to change it](http://nothingtodisplay.org/mac-os-x-set-desktop-image-from-terminal-app/) using the Terminal:

`sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db "update data set value = '/path/to/your/image.jpg'" && killall Dock`

So, if you want to run that after a file have changed (such as modyfing it through dropbox) you could use a file watcher script, such as [this Ruby one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26329244/274502).

Answer (score 1):

The previous method works, but there also is another (a little bit brutal) way.
You need LaunchAgent to monitor the file that is changing and execute an action when it is changed.

Save the following to a file in ~/Library/LaunchAgents/, you can use as filename 'com.yourname.programname.plist'). Replace `/full/path/to/desktoppicture`
 with the full path to the picture in your Dropbox folder.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.yourname.programname</string>
        <key>Program</key>
        <string>/usr/bin/killall</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>killall</string>
            <string>Dock</string>
        </array>
        <key>WatchPaths</key>
        <array>
            <string>/full/path/to/your/desktoppicture</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

After you modified and saved the property list, open the Terminal and type:

```
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.yourname.programname.plist
```

(replacing yourname.programname with whatever you called the plist file).

At this point, any time that the file is changed, `killall Dock` will be executed, quitting the Dock app and forcing a Desktop refresh. This is a bit brutal, and could be annoying since the Dock/Desktop refresh takes ~1 second and while it does you cannot use Mission Control and Dashboard, but it should be automatic.

In case you want to uninstall the LaunchAgent, first type:

```
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.yourname.programname.plist
```

(again, renaming the file to match yours), and then remove the plist file from ~/LaunchAgents/